# Setting a variable from object value and using it as a variable elsewhere

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl

I need to prepare a body text in JSTL/OGNL. Something like this:

```
First Name: <customer.fn>
Last Name: <customer.ln>
...
```

and use this in the mailto link. Customer comes from the `ActionContext`.

I tried the following:

```
<s:set var="bodyText" value="First Name: ${customer.fn}\n Last Name: ${customer.ln}....">
```

and I tried to print it like this, to see if its working.

```
<s:property value="#bodyText" />
```

But this does not seem to work.

Once I get the value, I need to use it in Mailto link like:

```
"mailto:xyz@abc.com?body=<s:property value="#bodyText">"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JSP EL in struts tag attribute, but you can use it in the tag body

```
<s:set var="bodyText">First Name: ${customer.fn}<br/> Last Name: ${customer.ln}</s:set>
```

Comment: How do I use/print that variable?

Comment: <s:property value="#bodyText" />

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: Man... Thanks a ton! I spent about 7 hours on this freaking thing..But I still don't know why the one I posted here doesn't work!!!